# how to download latest version of a file in http filelist with bash

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I would like to download the latest version of a file from http directory (by wget or curl). There is different files in that directory alongside the preferred one. The preferred file name is like filename_XYZ.zip, where XYZ is the version.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use

```
wget http://directory.com/filename_101.zip
```

Each time you like to download a different version just change the name of the file in the wget command.

```
 wget http://directory.com/filename_102.zip
```